# How to traverse with selectors in Jquery a callback data from a post-function like a document

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, callback, traversal

How can I perform with JQuery traversing a callback data coming from a post ajax like a document:

```
$.post(URL,function(data){
    alert($(data+'> div#xy').html(););
})
```

Comment: Assuming data is html, you mean something like alert($(data).find('div#xy').html();); ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create jQuery object from "data" by doing

```
var myData = $(data);
```

then you can simply use

```
var whatIWantToSelect = myData.find('enter selector here');
```

to find whatever you need

Comment: Thank you verry match for helping. :-)